# Hat Distribution Problem

Tags: graphs, combinatorics

I had a question for my paper last week and i tried solving but failed.

Given n people, any two are either friends or enemies, and friendship and enmity are mutual. I want to distribute hats to them, in such a way that any 2 friends possess a hat of the same color but no two enemies possess a hat of the same color. Each person can receive multiple hats. What is the minimum number of colors required to always guarantee that I can do this ?

Topic was about intro to graph theory.
It will be very helpful if anyone can provide a solution for this.
Thank you :)

Comment: This is not always possible, for example suppose $a,b$ and $b,c$ are friends, but $a,c$ are enemies.

Comment: @Ariel: $b$ could have 2 different hats (this is allowed in the problem statement) -- one the same colour as $a$'s, the other the same colour as $c$'s.  Then $a$ and $c$ can each have a single hat of different colours.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question? What have you tried, and where have you failed? Can you come up with any lower bounds or upper bounds? Can you solve any special cases?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by *minimum number of colors*? Are you interested in the minimum in terms of $n$, or in terms of the graph?

Comment: The answer is between $n^2/4$ and $\binom{n}{2}$.

Comment: What I did was, connect all the enemies, and the minimum number of hats required is equal to the max complete graph formed in the graph. Number of colors required in a complete graph when coloring is number of vertices. Is this a fine approach ? I did not get the marks though :P I plan to ask the teacher personally

Comment: I am not sure but seems like bipartite graph problem.